# Error with \tableofcontents, after switching from report documentclass to amsbook and back again

Tags: table-of-contents, report, amsbook

I changed my documentclass from `report` to `amsbook` (from AMSLaTeX) and everything was fine.
Then I decided to change it back to the `report` document class, but it will not compile. In order for it to compile, I am forced to comment out the `\tableofcontents` command. It gives the error message `undefined control sequence`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remove all auxiliary files and compile again.

Answer (score 9):

Let's see what happens when we compile the following file

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Title}
\section{X}
\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of the `.toc` file:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Title}{2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}X}{2}
```

When we change the first line of the file to be

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
```

the `.toc` file becomes

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{1}{Title}}{3}
\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{1}{X}}{3}
```

Thus we see that the `amsbook` class inserts some commands (`\tocchapter` and `\tocsection`) which are not understood by the standard class `report`; moreover it organizes the information in a slight different way.

One should also observe that the AMS classes are incompatible with `tocloft`, for a similar reason: they manage the `.toc` file in a different way.

### Solution

Remove the `.toc` file before compiling after having changed the class. This is  a good thing to do in such circumstances with all auxiliary files, so that we start afresh with the new document class.