# LaTeX Error: LaTeX Error: \tocsection undefined

Tags: errors, pandoc

I am working on a `.docx` to `.pdf` script that use pandoc and latex,

I got requested to use the following improvement:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%suppression des \vbox underfull badness
\def\@textbottom{\vskip \z@ \@plus 7pt}
\let\@texttop\relax
%numéros des sections en gras
\def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}
%formatage des sections
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0pt}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{-.5em}{\normalfont\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0pt}{6pt plus 2pt minus 0pt}{-.5em}{\normalfont\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}\z@{0pt}{18pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{\clearpage\normalfont\bfseries\centering}}
%\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}\z@{24pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{24pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{\normalfont\bfseries\centering}}
%lignes de points TOC
\newcommand\@dotsep{2}
%\def\l@chapter{\@tocline{0}{0pt}{0pt}{}{}}
%formatage numérotation TOC
\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]{\indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1\makebox[\widthof{00.}][l]{#2.}\quad}}#3\dotfill}
\renewcommand{\tocsubsection}[3]{\indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1\makebox[\widthof{00.00.}][l]{#2.}\quad}}#3\dotfill}
\renewcommand{\tocsubsubsection}[3]{\indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces#1\makebox[\widthof{00.00.00}][l]{#2.}\quad}}#3\dotfill}
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\,}
%no indent after theorem like environments
%\def\@endtheorem{\endtrivlist}
%ajuster les hauteurs d'indices
%\newcommand{\raisemath}[1]{\mathpalette{\raisem@th{#1}}}
%\newcommand{\raisem@th}[3]{\raisebox{#1}{$#2#3$}}
\makeatother
```

I have tried to use it with `--include-in-header` option of pandoc but it failed with :

```
LaTeX Error: Command \@dotsep already defined.
```

So I replaced

```
- \newcommand\@dotsep{2}
+ \renewcommand\@dotsep{2}
```

Now I have the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: \tocsection undefined.
```

Can anybody help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try ‘\renewcommand‘ or ‘\def‘ instead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! LaTeX's base classes already define `\@dotsep`, so it's normal that `\newcommand` raises an error. Try `\renewcommand` if you want to change the value of `\@dotsep`.

Comment: Thanks @PhelypeOleinik that did the trick... for that one... I have updated my question.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Make sure that `@` is a letter token when you do that. Try `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{2}`. However a few lines below in your code you already have `\renewcommand\@dotsep{2}` again, so I think you don't need to do that again...

Comment: Sorry, I have updated it once again with proper sourc e

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa The error says `LaTeX Error: \tocsection undefined`. The `\tocsection` command is from the `amsbook` document class, so unless you are using that class, it doesn't make much sense to define it... I think you can remove that line from your code (or change `\renewcommand\tocsection` to `\newcommand\tocsection`).

Comment: Editing `\renewcommand\tocsection` to `\newcommand\tocsection` work fine but now that you told me that I am using the wrong document class for this, I assume the author of this tex improvement expect me to use `amsbook` with it. How in `pandoc` can I switch to `amsbook` document class so I can try again?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I don't know `pandoc` so I can't help you further, sorry. But why do you need `pandoc` and LaTeX to convert from `.docx` to `.pdf`? Doesn't MS Word (or whatever software you're using) do that already? (P.S.: When replying to someone in the comments use `@<username>` so that they get a notification, for example, `@PhelypeOleinik` :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yes you can convert it normally but we want it generated with latex. Using `\newcommand\tocsection` the same as `\renewcommand\tocsection` if not in an `amsbook` document?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa `\newcommand` raises an error if the command is already defined while `\renewcommand` raises an error if the command is not yet defined (which explains the error messages you see), other than that they are exactly the same. Defining `\tocsection` if you're not using `amsbook` will most likely have no effect at all, so defining it or deleting it altogether should have the same outcome. Other than that yes, `\newcommand` will have the same effect.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik my current document class is defined with `\documentclass[12pt,french,]{article}` , how do you know that `\tocsection` command is from the `amsbook` document class? I have under the `\documentclass` declaration : `\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}`, does it mean  use ams ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa If you want `amsbook` you can change to `\documentclass[12pt,french,]{amsbook}` (which is _very_ different from `article`!). Answer to question 1: I searched `"\tocsection" command` and got [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252570/134574) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51594/134574) pages, then I looked at the source of `amsbook.cls`. Answer to question 2: loading the `amssymb` and `amsmath` packages is very different from loading the `amsbook` _class_.